# Python: Directional Navigation in 2d Array

Tags: python, arrays

**TLDR: I want to navigate all directions in a 2D array starting at the center**

I am trying to do a particular navigation in a 2D Python array. Say I have this 2D array (A1):

[image]

I want to navigate through this array and apply the summation of the index for A1 * index of A2 where A2 is another 2D array (A2):

[image]

When applying the summation, I want the current index, to start with the center of the second 2D array. So at A1[0][0] (1) I want to use the center of A2 (A2[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNVLx.png), or 0). I then want to move through each item in the second array and continue this process:

1(0) + 2(1) + 5(2) + 6(1)

This will take care of all the items from A2[center x][center y]. I then want to double back, and add all the values that are below the center. Here is a quick image illustrating what I want to do, one showing a case where we are out of bounds, and on, in bounds:

[image]

**What I am trying to do** is write a function that will navigate, from the center of a 2D array, out in each direction of that 2D array. Here is the code I have for it:

```
for row in range(A1.length):
    for column in range(A1[0].length):
        cRow = 0
        pSum = 0
        kRow = midRow - 1
        while kRow < A2.length and row + kRow < A1.length:
            kColumn = midColumn - 1
            cColumn = 0
            while kColumn < A2[0].length and column + kColumn < A1[0].length:
                pSum += float(A1[row + cRow][column + cColumn] * A2[kRow][kColumn])
                kColumn += 1
                cColumn += 1
            kRow += 1
            cRow += 1

        nKRow = midRow - 1
        cRow = 0
        #Get rows past
        while nKRow >= 0 and row - nKRow >= 0:
            nKColumn = midColumn - 1
            cColumn = 0
            while nKColumn >= 0 and column - nKColumn >= 0:
                # Account for row 0
                if row == 1 and cColumn == 0:
                    pSum += float(A1[0][column - cColumn] * A2[nKRow][nKColumn])
                else:
                    pSum += float(A1[row - cRow][column - cColumn] * A2[nKRow][nKColumn])
                nKColumn -= 1
                cColumn += 1
            nKRow -= 1
            cRow += 1


        value = float(pSum / average)
        A3[row][column] = value
```

This works in most cases, but does not work correctly in edge cases. The problem is that I am having issues setting values when row = 0 or column = 0.

**Is there a better approach to navigate every direction in a 2d array starting at the center?**

Comment: You may want to have a look at [`scipy.signal.convolve_2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do [kernel convolution](http://setosa.io/ev/image-kernels/), yes?

Where are midRow, midColumn, and average defined in your example?

Why do you have to start in the center of A2?  Summation and multiplication are both commutative operations, so the order shouldn't matter.  It would be much simpler to start in the top left corner of A2.  Something like (I haven't tested this):

```
kernelSize = 3
kernelOffset = int(kernelSize / 2) # Assumes only odd-sized kernels
for x in xrange(len(A1)):
    for y in xrange(len(A1[0])):
        total = 0
        for kx in xrange(kernelSize):
            for ky in xrange(kernelSize):
                offsetX = -kernelOffset + kx # Should give something in the range [-1, 1]
                offsetY = -kernelOffset + ky
                currentX = x + offsetX
                currentY = y + offsetY
                if currentX < 0 or currentX >= len(A1) or currentY < 0 or currentY >= len(A1[0]): # do nothing if "out of bounds"
                    continue
                total += A1[currentX][currentY] * A2[kx][ky]
        A3[x][y] = total
```